# Get all ManyToManyFields and ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm new in Django, this below are my classes, it's so that my Script has attributes for it self and globalattributes for all scripts.
My Question is now how I can ask to get all my attributes for my script.

so how to get all ManyToManyFields from GlobalAttribute for this Script

and

all ForeignKey from Attribute for this Script

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class GlobalAttribute(models.Model):
    GlobalAttributename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    GlobalAttributevalue = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.GlobalAttributename


class Script(models.Model):
    Scriptname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    Owner = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    GlobalAttribute = models.ManyToManyField(GlobalAttribute)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Scriptname

class Attribute(models.Model):
    Script = models.ForeignKey(Script, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Attributename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Attributevalue = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Attributename
```

I know my question is dumb.

Comment: Your questions could easily be answered by [reading the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Answer (score 0):

```
script = Script.objects.get(id=1)
script_global_attr = script.GlobalAttribute.all()
script_attr = script.attribute_set.all()
```

You can learn this if you have the time to read the documentation.

Django has great documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/